# PHP: call method in the context of each object of the inheritance chain

Tags: php

Look at the following code snippet:

```
<?php

class A {
        function fn() {
                print 'Context: Class:' . get_class($this) 
                        . ' Parent:' . get_parent_class($this) . "\n";
                if(get_parent_class($this)) {
                        parent::fn();
                }
        }
}

class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }

$a = new A();
$c = new C();

$a->fn();

print "\n";

$c->fn();

?>
```

By running it you will get the following output:

```
Context: Class:A Parent:

Context: Class:C Parent:B

Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in /home/andrei/test/test.php on line 10
```

I believe it should be something like this:

```
Context: Class:A Parent:

Context: Class:C Parent:B
Context: Class:B Parent:A
Context: Class:A Parent:
```

What do you think? If `get_parent_class($this)` returns a not false value should we safely assume parent:: is defined? In what class context is `fn()` called?

Comment: what output does (new B())->fn() produce?

Comment: Same error: 

Context: Class:B Parent:A

Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in /home/andrei/test/test.php

Comment: I think the title should be changed to a more descriptive one.

Comment: @CoryWalker Be my guest! You are free to change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calls using parent:: or self:: are considered to be static. These are supposed to be evaluated in the context of the defining class, not in the scope of the calling object. PHP 5.3 adds a new meaning to the word **static** which would be available for static calls *like* parent and self, but will be evaluated in the context of the **calling class**. This is called **Late Static Binding**. More info on this page:

http://www.php.net/lsb

**Edit:**

After some thought I believe this behavior is perfectly acceptable. First, let's see why would A want that its foo() method to call the foo() method of its parent, given that A has no parent. Because, it wants the method to always be executed regardless of the implementation of the children. If so, there are other solutions, not that nice though:

```
class A
{
    final public function __construct()
    {
        echo __METHOD__;

        $this->foo();

        $init = array($this, 'init');
        $args = func_get_args();

        call_user_func_array($init, $args);
    }

    // init would be used as a pseudo-constructor in children
    public function init()
    {}

    final private function foo()
    {
        echo __METHOD__;
    }
}

class B extends A
{}

class C extends B
{}

$c = new C;
```

If what you tried to do was to execute every foo() method in the chain, then it was expected behavior. If there was a B::foo() function then that would have been executed and if it had contain a call to parent::foo() then A::foo() would have been executed too.

So, probably parent::foo() is somehow confusing. It should be read like (sorry, but I couldn't find a better example):

the_first_parent_in_the_inheritance_chain_which_has_a_foo_method::foo()

That's what you are actually interested in. Why would you want to call foo() in the context of B? The only reason I can think of is for accessing private member from B. But then, how would A know what private members B has? It can't. You cannot use in A::foo() members that A hadn't declared. Unless A is abstract and defines some abstract methods. Of course, A may declare that property as private (B cannot give an overridden member a lower visibility than that in the parent and our aim is that B should have a private one).
Then B overrides that property, making it private as we want. Now, if your code would have worked, A or C would have had access to B's private member although it shouldn't. That breaks a rule.

Is there any situation in which you want the behavior you've asked about?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Strange stuff!

Comment: I have discovered this behaviour by helping a friend. Now I understand why things are the way they are. Thanks for explanations. I want to chat more with you about php and web apps. Contact me if you want at contact[at]andreisavu[dot]ro. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I am no php wizard but I would guess that the problem is with parent being static

Answer (score 1):

From my own experimentation prompted by your question, it seems that parent:: is resolved as the parent of the class the statement resides in.  Alter your test case as follows to see this behaviour:

```
<?php
class Z {
        function fn() {
                print "This is Z\n";
        }
}

class A extends Z {
        function fn() {
                print 'Context: Class:' . get_class($this)
                        . ' Parent:' . get_parent_class($this) . "\n";
                if(get_parent_class($this)) {
                        parent::fn();
                }
        }
}
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }
$a = new A();
$c = new C();
$a->fn();
print "\n";
$c->fn();
?>
```

I agree this is not intuitive and may be a bug.

UPDATE:
Interesting what happens when you use this to call the parent instead:

```
eval(get_parent_class($this). "::fn();");
```

Comment: I believe it's a bug because the function should be called in the context of the child class.

Comment: It's seems the context is never set as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is wrong. If ur class C has fn() function defined then it would never call fn() in class A, so ther is no meaning in saying parent::fn bcoz ur parent doesnt have function called fn, thts the reason its falling back on fn() defined in A.

But if u want to call some other function in the current object context **use $this instead of parent**. Herez code for this.

```
<?php

class A {
        function fn() {
                print 'Context: Function:'.__FUNCTION__.' Class:' . get_class($this)
                        . ' Parent:' . get_parent_class($this) . "\n";
                if(get_parent_class($this)) {
                        $this->fB();
                }
        }
}

class B extends A { }
class C extends B {
        function fB(){
                print 'Context: Function:'.__FUNCTION__.' Class:' . get_class($this)
                        . ' Parent:' . get_parent_class($this) . "\n";
        }
}

$a = new A();
$c = new C();

$a->fn();

print "\n";

$c->fn();

?>

**out put**
Context: Function:fn Class:A Parent:

Context: Function:fn Class:C Parent:B
Context: Function:fB Class:C Parent:B
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you try to call parent->fn()
I've never tried stuff like this before, but that would be my first guess..